# Is it necessary for a microsoft teams bot to be accessible publicly?

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

In "[Get started on the Microsoft Teams platform with C#/.NET and App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio)" its stated that

> Remember that apps in Microsoft Teams are web applications exposing
>   one or more capabilities. For the Teams platform to load your app,
>   your app must be reachable from the internet.

Is it enough to have the application available  for the user who is working with teams (like in the local network) or does the internet mean the internet here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user types in command in chat textbox in Microsoft Teams, this is routed to backend chat service which then calls your bot endpoint specified in Bot setting. That's the reason having user and code on the same network won't help. Your bot has to be publicly accessible over internet. Here is simple bot flow:

[image: Bot Messages]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the internet means the internet.

To expand upon this a bit, your bot can be deployed locally or on your own servers, but it must have a publicly accessible endpoint as the communication is routed through Microsoft Chat Services, and does not hit your bot directly.

Comment: @Michael - When user types in command in chat textbox, this is routed to backend bot service and which then calls your bot endpoint specified in Bot setting. That's the reason having user and code on the same network won't help. Your bot has to be publicly accessible over internet.

Comment: Fair call - I would have just added it as a comment, and most answers like this come from people without the reputation to comment. Deleted.